# Prevent Touch Screen Keyboard from Hiding (Windows 11)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, touch-typing

Do you know a way to prevent the new Touch Screen Keyboard (not the old osk.exe) from disappearing form screen while physical keystrokes are sent on Windows 11? I only would like it to hide on keypress, e.g. F12. Looking forward to your hack ;)

Comment: not with the built-in touch screen keyboard - it's quite light on options. You would need to use the on-screen keyboard instead if you want it visible after a physical keyboard press